# Dividing a verilog genvar

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

So I'm building a tree in Verilog. The tree will assign element j of level i to the smaller of [j,j+1] of level i+1.

The issue here is I'm not sure how verilog treats the divide operator for genvar's:

```
genvar i,j;
generate
  for(i = LEVELS; i > 0; i--) begin
    for(j = 0; j < 2**i; j = j + 2) begin // 0..7 for level 3, 0..3 for level 2, 0..1 for level 1 and 0 for level 0
      assign tree[i-1][j/2] = tree[i][j] <operator> tree[i][j+1];
    end
  end
endgenerate
```

The issue here is I'm not sure that `j/2` above will be floored so that 1/2 == 0. Anyone know if this is true?

Answer (score 3):

This simulation demonstrates that, if `j` is odd, then `j/2` will be floored:

```
module tb;

wire [7:0] tree [4];

genvar j;
generate
    for (j=1; j<8; j=j+2) begin
        assign tree[j/2] = j;
    end
endgenerate

initial begin
    #1;
    for (int k=0; k<4; k++) $display("tree[%0d] = %0d", k, tree[k]);
end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
tree[0] = 1
tree[1] = 3
tree[2] = 5
tree[3] = 7
```

In this code, `j` has only odd values: 1, 3, 5, 7.

So `j/2` resolves to the even values: 0, 1, 2, 3.

---

As an aside: in your code, you can't have 1/2. `j` can only be 0,2,4,6... So, `j/2` can only be 0,1,2,3...

Answer (score 3):

integer division is always floored:

> IEEE 1800-2017: 11.4.2: The integer division shall truncate any fractional part toward zero.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is j/2, why not just replace it with (j>>1)? There's less chance of 
 tools misinterpreting it.
LRM is not carved in stone, I've seen lots of CAD tools taking it to pretty irrational places.

Comment: I actually wasn’t aware you could bitshift genvars. Since I’m not sure what type they end up being.